Bosch Dishwasher Supply Line too long
I am trying to figure out how to install a long dishwasher supply line without bends.
Background
I recently purchased a new Bosch dishwasher and found out that instead of requiring a separate braided hose, it comes with its own supply line with solenoid at the end of it and a small braided hose "adapter" after that.
Problem
The problem is that my original pipes were Poly-B and so I have been told that I need to use an adapter from the end of the Poly-B to a length of PEX and then add a compression fitting to hook up the supply line. Using shark bite adapters, this means an additional 3-4" from cut Poly-B shown in the photo below.
The hose is quite long and the solenoid needs to stay inside the cabinet area so I'm not sure how to set this up so that the line does not have tight bends/kinks in it.

Some additional questions:

Do I still need the hammer arrestor in the picture? The dishwasher manual does not mention them and I've seen some comments online that modern dishwashers may not require them anymore.

a. If I can remove the hammer, is there anyway to hook either PEX  or the braided hose directly to the Dishwasher shutoff valve shown in the photo? (My greatest worry is that I'll need to replace that as well which requires shutting off the Main...)

Is it OK to coil/loop a supply line vertically (i.e. up against the wall on the left) ?



Yes, you can absolutely coil the excess hose and stash it vertically.
I’d leave the hammer arrestor in place, as it’ll benefit the rest of the water system.
